# Order of growth according to Big-O Notation

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

[image]

Hello Stack Users, I am having trouble finishing this growth according to size algorithm problem. I was able to figure out the first two of the problem which are not listed in the picture. That would be 1. O(1) and 3. O(N) I was able to place these into their correct slots. I still cannot figure out how to determine the growth rate for 2,4,5,6 into the slots provided. Any suggestions on how to determine this?

Comment: The second one would be O(N^2) since it loops from [1,N] and [1,N] again inside each of those

Answer (score 2):

1. `O(N)`

The first for loop takes `N` and the second also takes `N` so

```
O(N) = N + N = 2N = N
```

2. `O(N^2)`
   The first for loop takes `N` and the second also `N`, but in this case it is nested.  inner loop takes `N` for every other loop of outer loop

   O(N) = N * N = O(N^2)
3. `O(N)`

The first for loop it takes `N` and the second also `5`, but it is nested so

```
O(N) = 5 * N = 5N = O(N)
```

4. `O(log(N))`

   to divide a number `N` by `2` continuously until it reaches `1`, it takes 
   `log(N)`

Comment: Are you sure the answers are reusable

Comment: I am sorry answers aren't reusable I should have stated that. Answer 1 and answer 3 are gone so there are only 4 options left to choose from from one for each problem.

Comment: He got number 2 and 4 right